# How to await call method until observers works?

Tags: angular, typescript2.0, angular6

I have some observable functions:

```js
function a(): Observable<any> { }

function b(): Observable<any> { }
```

After I join these observables to one:

```js
let awaitingObservers = [a(), b()];

public getObservables() {
  forkJoin(awaitingObservers).subscribe(results => {
    return results;
  });
}
```

So, last function that I call is:

```js
function start() {

  if (this.currentForm().functions) {
    this.currentForm().functions.iterate();
    this.currentForm().functions.getObservables();
  }

  /* Return next form */

  this.current = nextForm;

}
```

This function cheks if exits any observable method to call then calls then `this.currentForm().functions.iterate();`

After subsribes them on line: `this.currentForm().functions.getObservables();`.

How to wait this process and dont while all observables returns result, only then call: `this.current = nextForm;`?

My problem is:

- If exist list of observables, call them, only then execute line: `this.current = nextForm;`

Comment: I can suppose to return Observer in `forkJoin()`. Then subscribe on this and call inside: `this.current = nextForm;`

Comment: I meant something like: `public getObservables(): Observable<any> {
    return forkJoin(this.awaitingObservers).subscribe(results => {
      return Observable.of(results);
    });
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stream your forked stream further to the start function

```
public getObservables():Observable<[X,Y]>{
    return forkoin(awaitingObservers);
}
```

and then await the result where you want to process it

function start() {

```
if (this.currentForm().functions) {
      this.currentForm().functions.iterate();
      this.currentForm().functions.getObservables().subscribe( data => this.current = nextForm)
    }
}
```

Why i would do it like that?
The method "getObservables" is just a convenience method to do the forking. It´s not the real processor of the data.
The processor of the result is in your "start" function. And i think the processor should always be responsible to trigger the subscription. 
Because of that, i would do the subscribing in the start function.

warm regards

Comment: Cool, you mean return istantly Observer from Fork, then subscibe on this

Comment: What will be if one Observer returns false, error? I need to be ensure that all observers are executed without problems

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html
If one Observable goes rogue, you lose all results. But you can catch the error as normal.